# MYSQL : Error in Tigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

This is my query for creating trigger. Something wrong in it but I am not able to find it.

**What I need by trigger** - I want to create trigger for total_login column. I have last_login column in same table. I am updating last_login column when user get login. So I want create trigger for that purpose.

Can anyone do help?

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  updateTotalLogin AFTER UPDATE ON users
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if NEW.last_login <> OLD.last_login
then
       UPDATE users SET total_login = (total_login + 1) ;
end if
END
```

Comment: What you want to write is something that updates a table when the table gets updated. Can't you see where this is going? Hint: update...update...update...update...update...update...update...update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try using delimiter..

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  TRIGGER  updateTotalLogin BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.last_login <> OLD.last_login THEN
   SET NEW.total_login = OLD.total_login + 1;
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another UPDATE, you can set this column just here in the trigger. I would recommend using a BEFORE UPDATE trigger too:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  updateTotalLogin BEFORE UPDATE ON users
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 if NEW.last_login <> OLD.last_login
 then
       SET NEW.total_login = OLD.total_login + 1;
 end if
 END
```

Comment: It throws error : `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.total_login = OLD.total_login + 1' at line 6 `

Comment: I missed the SET as fancyPants mentioned. Fixed now.

Comment: Still error throwing : `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 `